# What is the meaning of “cascading” in Cascading Style Sheets?

Tags: css, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the meaning of “cascading ” in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043001/what-is-the-meaning-of-cascading-in-css)

What’s cascading in Cascading Style Sheets?

Comment: @Gumbo: Nice, we retagged each question [terminology] at around the same time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) describes in what order properties are applied on elements.