# HTML email's inline CSS keeps getting stripped when displayed in Yahoo and Gmail

Tags: gmail, html-email, inline-styles, yahoo-mail, css

I'm creating an HTML email and testing it out by sending it through Outlook. However, when viewing in Gmail or Yahoo! Mail the inline styles are being stripped from the email. Without the `display:block` style, the images are displaying with gaps in between.

The code validated with no errors.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would guess you have a rule included that they don't like. Take a look [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3652/gmail-strips-out-inline-css).

Comment: The word "[Cascading][1]" before "Stylesheets" is pretty significant.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043001/what-is-the-meaning-of-cascading-in-css

Comment: When you say stripped, do you mean removed from the code, or just ineffective? Might want to post some before/after code so we can see what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that outlook is actually stripping them before sending. Or coverting them to something gmail/yahoo can't understand.

Try testing with a tool like http://putsmail.com/ , Then let me know if it's still happening.