# Why doesn't this case of display inline work?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to arrange the content like a 2 X 3 table would, but using css. However when I try to use inline-block it doesn't work(I have tried multiple browsers). See the items tagged with the "content" class.This is what I'm trying to do "http://aggiebass.net63.net/"
Edit: After changing ".content div ul li" to ".content ul li" the text still doesn't act correctly.

```html
<head><style>
  .content{
    background-color:white;
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
  }
  .content img{
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
  }
 .content ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
</style></head><body>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><div class="tbox">
        <img src="Calendar.jpg" >
        <h2>Calendar</h2>
        <p>Check here to moniter meetings and other events. Additionally this calendar can be synchronized with other calendar programs.</p>
      </div></li>
      <li><div class="tbox">
        <img src="Calendar.jpg" >
        <h2>Resources</h2>
        <p>When you join BASS you not only benafit from a strong community but also from our club resources such as our class notes & study guide database.</p>
      </div></li>
      <li><div class="tbox">
        <img src="Contact.jpg" >
        <h2>Newsfeed</h2>
        <p>Catch up on the latest club news. Check here for anouncments and details on recent club events. This feed is also availible on facebook.</p>
      </div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This is why I just DGAF and use tables anyway. -shrugs- If I want something to look like a table, I use a table. Much easier.

Comment: You should consider using `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` to transform semantic markup into an actual internal table-based layout.

Comment: Your code as posted (whose indentation I have 'corrected') is missing a closing `}` on your last CSS rule. It's also missing an opening `<html>` tag, but I assume you have that.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because your CSS is incorrect. `.content div ul li` is looking for a div descendant of `.content` (and there isn't one). It should be:

```
.content ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sw84z0uo/)**

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but the text still expands past the pictures for some reason.

Comment: That's because your container div is wider than the pictures. The text fills the width but the images don't.

Answer (score 1):

`.content div ul li` does not exist, instead you should use:

```
.content ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
.content div ul li
```

to

```
.content ul li
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in your CSS
You are not cascading your element correctly. I think you wanted to do something like

```
div.content ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Not

```
.content div ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
```

The second one is not valid for your HTML structure

Comment: What is the name of that technique? Is it called cascading?

Comment: Actually, @bn00d, hierarchical descendant selectors in CSS are unrelated to the word 'cascading' in the title. "Cascading" means that multiple "conflicting styles can be applied to the same document and there is a well-defined "cascade" of how they are applied. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043001/what-is-the-meaning-of-cascading-in-css

Comment: See also how the co-author of CSS defines it: http://people.opera.com/howcome/2006/phd/#h-357

Comment: @Phrogz I'll take my comment back, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the syntax fixed the issue for the pictures, but still let the paragraphs underneath sprawl.

Correcting the syntax and adding a class for the paragraphs seems to work.

```
  div.tbox {
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
  }
```