# Conflicting a href links?

Tags: hyperlink, href

So I'm trying to make a website with two different links- however, the CSS that I'm editing them with recognizes them both as "a" and puts them in the same spot. This is aggervating, I've tried basing the css off of the  they're in, but that doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code:

```
<html>

<h1>
<div id = "firstbutton">
<a href="http://google.com">GOOGLE</a>

    <style type="text/css">
        a {
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            font-size: 60;
            font-family: Arial;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -85px;
            margin-left: -145px;
        }
    </style>
    </div>



    <div id = "forumbutton">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Forum</a>
        <style type="text/css">
         a{
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            font-size: 30;
            font-family: Calibri;
            position: fixed;
            text-decoration: none;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: 260px;
            margin-left: -45px;
        }
    </style>
    </div>

</h1>




<body>


    <audio src="goingdown.mp3" autoplay></audio>

    <style type="text/css">
   body {

    background-image: url('spacewallpaper.jpg');

}
    </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where classes come in handy. You should add a class attribute to each `a` and define your CSS with that class. Or you could use an ID.

Styles can get overridden with multiple style blocks or declarations. It doesn't apply the the closest tag.

Comment: Your "cascading" definition is partly true, but more accurately, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043001/what-is-the-meaning-of-cascading-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Set ID for each ***a*** element

Then css should look like:

```
a#name1{ ... }
a#name2{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed code
[JS Fiddle - Working](https://jsfiddle.net/g3saahdh/)

```
 .GClass a {
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            font-size: 60;
            font-family: Arial;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -85px;
            margin-left: -145px;
        }
.FClass  a{
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            font-size: 30;
            font-family: Calibri;
            position: fixed;
            text-decoration: none;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: 260px;
            margin-left: -45px;
        }


<html>

<h1>
<div id = "firstbutton">
<a href="http://google.com" class="GClass">GOOGLE</a>

    </div>



    <div id = "forumbutton">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="FClass">Forum</a>

    </div>

</h1>




<body>


    <audio src="goingdown.mp3" autoplay></audio>

    <style type="text/css">
   body {

    background-image: url('spacewallpaper.jpg');

}
    </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set and **ID** for each element you are trying to add (implement), then you can call that element easily inside the **CSS**.

Also Element `div` cannot be nested inside element `h1`!

The `font-size` should be marked in pixels. Example  `font-size: 30px;`.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your document is slightly scattered...

it is better to put all your styles in the head section an not scattered through the body section

```
<html>

  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
      background-image: url('spacewallpaper.jpg');
    }
    a
    {
      color: #FFFFFF; 
      text-decoration: none;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
    .FirstLink
    {
      font-size: 60; 
      font-family: Arial; 
      position: fixed;
      margin-top: -85px;
      margin-left: -145px;
    }
    .SecondLink
    {
      font-size: 30;
      font-family: Calibri;
      position: fixed;
      margin-top: 260px;
      margin-left: -45px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <h1>
    <div id = "firstbutton">
      <a class="FirstLink" href="http://google.com">GOOGLE</a>
    </div>

    <div id = "forumbutton">
      <a class="SecondLink" href="http://www.google.com">Forum</a>
    </div>
  </h1>

  <audio src="goingdown.mp3" autoplay></audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try the code above and compare it to your own for reference to see the differences. Good luck.