# When using container in React-Boostrap my body's background-color is overwritten

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am in the process of introducing myself to react bootstrap. So far I have the following in npm:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

From there, I have made my parent element in `App.js` a container:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Link, Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App container">
       ...
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

And I also  have bootstrap imported according to the reactBootStrap documentation:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Next, I have edited my `index.css` so that my my container class has a white background and my body has a teal background:

```css
body {
    background-color: teal;
}
    
.container {
    background-color: white;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that my entire page shows a white background. When I open up inspect, it shows that my body did have a teal `background-color`, but it was overridden, but I  am not sure when in my code it was overwritten. Does anyone have any experience with such an issue? My goal is to have a white container, with a teal background on either side of the container when I view my page.

Comment: In Chrome for example when you inspect the element you can see the active property, with the related class name just above it, check that, is it a random string or a clear one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS stands for *Cascading Style Sheets* - **Cascading** being the key word here. In the React template the `index.html` (where `index.css` is applied) actually loads `App.js` and and `App.css` afterwards.

Consequently, this means that any file applied or loaded after `index.css` that have a matching CSS rule will overwrite the CSS rules you added in `index.css`.

The best solution here is to add `import "./App.css"` to the top of your `./App.js` and add your rules to `App.css`. That way they are loaded and the end of chain and they should overwrite everything applied beforehand:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Link, Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App container">
        text in a container
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Then, in your App.css, add:

```css
body {
        background-color: teal;
}

.container{
        background-color: white;
}
```

After doing this you essentially end up with the following:

[image]

You can read more about cascading here on SO in the following question:
[What is the meaning of "cascading' in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043001/what-is-the-meaning-of-cascading-in-css)